# Unable to perform update on my question in SPFX. Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error making HttpClient request in queryable [400] odata.error

Tags: sharepoint, odata, web-parts, spfx

I have fixed this issue on one of my earlier projects but it seems like I am unable to do it on this project and I don't know why.

The fix that I have done earlier was by adding `delete updateFAQ["odata.metadata"]`
Though the error vscode gives now is the following:
*Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"odata.metadata"' can't be used to index type 'IFAQ. Property 'odata.metadata' does not exist on type 'IFAQ'*

For context the method looks like this:

```
    public async updateFAQ(updateFAQ: IFAQ): Promise<void> {
        delete updateFAQ["odata.metadata"] //vscode gives an error 
        await this._sp.web.lists.getById(this.faqListId).items.getById(updateFAQ.ID).update(updateFAQ);
    }
```

Can someone give some guidance on why the error occurs and why `delete updateFAQ["odata.metadata"]`  gives an error?

If there is anything that you need context to just say the word.

The full error in the console looks like this: `Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error making HttpClient request in queryable [400]  ::> {"odata.error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"A relative URI value 'Web/Lists(guid'e6197c8f-88c1-47c4-911e-538ee0638250')/Items(25)' was specified in the payload, but the odata.metadata annotation is missing from the payload. The payload must only contain absolute URIs or the odata.metadata annotation must be on the payload."}}} at HttpRequestError.init (parsers.js:96:1) at async Proxy.errorCheck (parsers.js:45:1) at async queryable.js:118:1`

EDIT: Interface

```
export interface IFAQ {
    ID?: number;
    Question: string;
    Answer: string;
}
```

UPDATE/SOLUTION
I've got it fixed. What I did was by mapping the result sp.web.lists into an object called  `finalResult`where I set the object properties to the properties of the IFAQ. Then I return finalResult. In that way I choose that I only want to return the properties of the IFAQ and not any metadata or odata:

```
    public async getFAQ(): Promise<IFAQ[]> {
        let result: IFAQ[] = await this._sp.web.lists.getById(this.faqListId).items();        

        let finalReuslt = result.map((x) => ({
            ID: x.ID,
            Question: x.Question,
            Answer: x.Answer
        }))
        
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: maybe your interface does not have "odata"? But you can just parse updateFAQ to any and delete like "delete (updateFAQ as any)["odata.metadata"];"

Comment: Correct, my intercace does not have any of the odata. Usually I just delete the odata that gives the error, which in this case is "odata.metadata", with the following code: delete updateFAQ["odata.metadata"] . On my old project this wasn't an issue. I've tried your method by adding  ```delete (updateFAQ as any)["odata.metadata"]; ``` Though it gave the same error

Comment: I've got it fixed. What I did was by mapping the result sp.web.lists into an object called ``` finalResult```where I set the object properties to the properties of the IFAQ. Then I return finalResult. In that way I choose that I only want to return the properties of the IFAQ and not any metadata or odata.